# Java Optional check for object and its property

Tags: java, option-type

I wanted to check if object is not null and its property is not null then call another function. I am trying to do this with Optional.

Employee is a class with a string property name. So I wanted to check if employee object is not null and name property in it is not null then call a method.

I tried some thing like below, but is this right approach, please correct me.

```
   //Employee emp; // comes from another function
    Optional.ofNullable(emp).ifPresent(obj -> Optional.ofNullable(obj.getName()).ifPresent(name ->System.out.println(name)));
```

Comment: You want to use `Optional.flatMap`. I think this function is not available in java 8 so you need to write some ugly code.

Comment: Actually, `Optional.map` will automaticall convert `null` to `Optional.empty` so you can use that

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you want

```
Optional.ofNullable(emp).map(Employee::getName).ifPresent(System.out::println);
```